# pipeline function of sklearn for self built functions

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Function is as follows:

```
def lin_fit():

    data=pd.read_csv('Advertising.csv')

    x=data[:,1]
    y=data[:,3]
    output_array= np.zeros(12)
    for j in range(2,14):

        model_fit_new=sp.polyfit(x,y,j, full=True)
        print(model_fit_new[1])
        output_array[j-2]= model_fit_new[1]

    return output_array
```

Pipeline function: with inbuilt function Imputer and my own function lin_fit

```
estimator = Pipeline([("imputer", Imputer(missing_values=0,
                                      strategy="mean",
                                      axis=0)), ("linear_fit", lin_fit())])
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: unhashable type

Answer (score 0):

From the pipeline docs:

"Sequentially apply a list of transforms and a final estimator. Intermediate steps of the pipeline must be ‘transforms’, that is, they must implement fit and transform methods. The final estimator only needs to implement fit."

So you have to implement these methods. You probably have to stick to other sklearn conventions as well e.g. inherit from BaseEstimator, and ensure all your parameters are explicitly listed in the **init** of the class.